# Database Design; How to store weeks efficiently?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I need to create a table to store the number of hours a person will work each week on each task. The table will look like this:

```
[TaskID] [User] [Week 1] [Week 2] ....... [Week 52]  [Year]
```

so my question is, will I run into a performance issue with such database design? I can always find the right reference of which week it is. e.g Week 2 = Jan 3, 2011 - Jan 9, 2011.

And what is the best way to handle leap year? like December 26, 2011 - Jan 1, 2012. I guess I can consider this still as the last week of 2011.

Any advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your illustration.  If those represent column names, then this is a poor database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is very denormalized data, and not recommended.  Data is meant to grow *down* and not *out*.  Something like this would be advisable:

```
create table YourWeeks
(
    TaskID int identity(1, 1) not null,
    User varchar(100) not null,
    Week varchar(100) not null,
    WeekEnum int not null,
    Year int not null,
    constraint ck_weeknum check (WeekEnum between 1 and 52)
)
go
```

And to handle leap years you can get fancy with a foreign key reference, like so:

```
create table Years
(
    Year int not null,
    IsLeapYear bit not null
)
go

alter table YourWeeks
add constraint fk_weeks foreign key (Year) references Years (Year)
go
```

Comment: You could even go with a `TaskId`-`UserId`-`Date`-`NumberOfHours` structured table, then create a view which groups the accumulated time by week.

Comment: @slugster Agreed, there are many ways to approach this design, and that is also a good one.

Comment: "very denormalized data" -- care to state which normal form you think it is and why? Hint: you may have misunderstood [what repeating groups in the context of 1NF really means](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=712).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will run into a performance issue with such a design. You will have many, many fields which are completely useless and empty, but which you will have to scan every time you want to do a query.

You would be better off having a structure like this:

```
TaskID
User
WeekNumber
Year
Hours
```

As for your other question... "leap year" has nothing to do with the dates you mention. But we can't necessarily answer how to handle those; that's more of a business rule thing - what does the business consider to be the start of week 1?

Answer (score 2):

Using the same format you used in your question, I would set up the following three normalized tables:

## USERS

```
[id] [name]
```

## TASKS

```
[id] [description]
```

## HOURS

```
[id] [task_id] [user_id] [year] [week_no] [hours]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use [a calendar table with a julianized date attribute](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-data-techniques-in-sql-/).